# Standardization based on subsamples

Tags: standardization, z-score, control-group

I need to analyze data on the cognitive performance in a sample of participants divided into clinical (36 participants) and non-clinical groups (~100 participants).

What would be the correct approach to calculate z-scores? Is it correct to estimate z-scores for the entire sample based only on the healthy control mean scores and standard deviations, as they are considered a reference group and the patients are expected to have significantly lower scores in some measures?

Comment: Could you explain why you have a need to compute z-scores and what you intend them to represent?

Comment: I need to analyze data on cognitive performance in different tasks, from a sample including 36 patients and ~100 healthy controls. The groups do not differ regarding age and other relevant characteristics, so i'm trying to explore cognitive decline across domains (e.g. memory, attention, etc).

It is current practice to standardize the cognitive battery's test scores, they are used to calculate task efficiency (accuracy/speed), for ex. What would be the correct approach? Patients have worse performance. Wouldn't z-transform based on the complete sample rather than controls-only be biased?

Comment: Your first question is on topic, but your second question is about code, and that is off topic. If you remove the second question, I will vote to reopen.